# WordPress: How to update data in database using PHP with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, mysqli

I am using core PHP to make WordPress custom page template for my website, but when I am updating user id, it was not updating the user id.

Suppose I have a user in database and when the user pay amount using PayPal, make that user id 1. By default its id is 0.

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE user_register SET pay_status = '$pay_status' WHERE wp_user_id = $current_user" ) );
```

I want to make that user status to 1 when paid.

Comment: Is `$pay_status` set somewhere in your code?

Comment: Not updating `\`wp_user_id\`` or not updating `\`pay_status\``?

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting arbitrary data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work. But without knowing the full source code we don't know why it doesn't work.

Although you can do update `$wpdb->query`, $wpdb does have a better way to update a row. Use `$wpdb->update` instead.

```
if($user_is_paying){
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'user_register';
    $data = array('pay_status'=>$pay_status);
    $where = array('wp_user_id'=>$current_user);
    $wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RamGhadiyaram I have added additional commentary to the answer.